# jQuery data-attributes cross-browser safe

Tags: jquery

Is jQuery's

```
$('selector').data("name"); /* data-name */
```

cross-browser save? Is there anything I should watch out for?

Thanks.

Comment: In some cases it is important to note, that updates via `data()` are just reflected within jQuery data object and not in the DOM element. So you can not set `data-x` attributes via `data()`!

Comment: ... and that's exactly why it's safe to do. ) In fact, even if it were setting data attributes, it would have been done via Element.setAttribute method, which is also universally supported.

Comment: Will not be setting the attribute dynamically, but thanks for pointing this out. @Sirko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not counting possible bugs, all jQuery methods are meant to be compatible and function identically between all browsers supported by the version of jQuery you're using (unless the API says otherwise). That's pretty much the whole idea of using jQuery.

The only thing the API says about [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is:

> Note that this method currently does not provide cross-platform support for setting data on XML documents, as Internet Explorer does not allow data to be attached via expando properties.